# usb to ethernet driver installation

Tags: kernel, usb-drivers

I am following this thread to enable my samsung android phone to do usb to ethernet communication

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2039886

I copied the smsc75xx.ko generated by the user Brandi into system/lib/modules folder. But when i tried to do insmod or modprobe to load the driver, this is what i get

root@android:/system/lib/modules # insmod smsc75xx.ko 
insmod: can't insert 'smsc75xx.ko': invalid module format

uname -r returns the following kernel version

3.0.8-perf-T769UVLH5-CL990184

Can you please help me compile for this kernel version? or suggest alternative paths to solve this issue.

I am completely new to android world and would appreciate step by step instructions with examples.

Best Regards,

Comment: your link is invalid. there are "...." in the url and results in a 404.

Comment: See my answers to: [Is it possible to add a driver to my kernel without flashing a new kernel?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214736/218526) and [where kernel modules are installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209519/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a kernel module (noticeable at the `.ko` extension) as a software module (typically `.jar` or `.so`) Those `.ko` modules have to be compiled together with the kernel. You can't load them with a command, they have to be loaded by the kernel. If your kernel supports that module, then copying and rebooting is enough and the module should load and run. If it doesn't do so then you need a custom kernel with that module already built in.

Comment: Any idea where do i find the source code for kernel 3.0.8-perf-T769UVLH5-CL990184 and the steps needed to compile the source code against this kernel.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If the device manufacturer himself hasn't published the sources or you can't find them, then there might be a custom kernel on xda-developers for your device with sources on eg. GitHub. If you're lucky then there might also be a tutorial on how to compile a custom kernel for your device. I don't own that device and also never tried to compile a custom kernel so you may want to ask some users on xda about that module.

Comment: where can i find the tool chain for this kernel 3.0.8-perf-T769UVLH5-CL990184 ?

Comment: This guide may help you out to build and compile your own kernel as I don't know what device you are searching the sources for: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2152819

Comment: Hi GiantTree. Here is the device information. samsung galaxy S blaze-4g sgh-t769,
android version = 4.04,
Basedband version = T769UVMB1,
Kernel version=3.0.8-perf-T769ULVH5-CL990184

Comment: Browse to Samsungs Opensource website and search for your device (model no.). I did this already for you so go here: http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=sgh-t769 and download the `ICS` file `SGH-T769_NA_TMB_ICS_Opensource.zip`, agree to their conditions and work with the source. I don't actually know if the kernel is included but it should as far as I know.

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help people who don't have a clue on how to move on.

Comment: I think your answer needs some corrections: ***"modules have to be compiled together with the kernel"***. That's the recommended way but may work otherwise too. ***"You can't load them with a command, they have to be loaded by the kernel. If your kernel supports that module, then copying and rebooting is enough and the module should load and run."***. Modules are loaded with a command from userspace. Kernel doesn't load them automatically.