# Where are kernel modules installed?

Tags: installation, kernel, builds

I am trying to find Linux kernel modules on my nitrogen board.

I have unpacked kernel config from `/proc/config.gz` and I see kernel was compiled with a lot of modules.

I see only one in `/vendor/lib/modules`, zero in `/system/lib/modules`.

Can somebody explain where modules installed, what is procedure to install modules?

Comment: In theory they could be in a startup ramdisk.  It's also possible to build modules but not packaged them (in which case they would not be usable, but stranger things have happened).  If there is a particular *goal* you have you should edit that into your question - ie, are you trying to find a module you think is available, but which has not been loaded?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways Linux kernel modules are built: **1.** as a part of kernel executable binary (compressed image) i.e. with `CONFIG_*=y` options at build time, or **2.** as separate kernel object (`.ko`) files that can be loaded and unloaded with some conditions i.e. built with `CONFIG_*=m` options.
In second case the `.ko` files are placed on some standard location(s), usually `/lib/modules/` on Linux and its equivalent on Android `/system/lib/modules/` or `/vendor/lib/modules/`. These paths are hard-coded in binaries that load them e.g. `insmod`, `modprobe`.

On pre-Pie releases <sup>([1](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/modular-kernels#loadable-kernel-modules))</sup>, by-default Android kernel is built without option `CONFIG_MODULES=y`, so there are no kernel modules built as `.ko` files which can be loaded or unloaded with `insmod`, `modprobe` or `rmmod` as is the case with standard Linux distros. Nor they are exposed through `/proc/modules` from where `lsmod` reads information. However each kernel component that can be built as a module has an entry in `/sys/module`.

Now those modules which are compiled and loaded as `.ko` file has a corresponding `/sys/module/<module>/initstate` file, others don't have. You can confirm this way if there are any loaded modules:

```
~$ ls /sys/module/*/initstate
```

Comment: Though *default* Android might not use loadable modules, many *actual devices* have for years.

Comment: Yes, I do have 20+ modules on my device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I have been trying to locate the `*.ko` files on my emulator, but can't seem to find them anywhere. It is an API 30 emulator, and I can see the modules loaded (in `/proc/modules`), and the appropriate file exists for `/sys/module/*/initstate`, but no `*.ko` files exist (looked with `find / -name "*.ko"`. Any idea where else they could be?

Comment: @WilliamReed OEMs / ROM developers might name the loadable module files differently. You may look into `init` configuration files (`*.rc`) in `/system` and `/vendor` to see how and from where modules are loaded on boot. `grep -riI <mod_name> /system /vendor /odm /product` or `find /system /vendor /odm /product -iname '*<mod_name>*'` (don't append `.ko`) should lead to some conclusion.

Comment: Official guidance for placing `.ko` files in fs: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/loadable-kernel-modules#file-locations

Answer (score 1):

Kernel modules is a piece of code which load into kernel memory. It consists of at least two functions like int, cleanup.
If you want to see which modules are loaded into kernel memory, just type the commands:
`lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules`.
If you want to find kernel modules in whole memory of system partition: 
`find / -name "*.ko"`.

**Load kernel module into memory**

```
insmod hello.ko
```

**Remove kernel module**

```
rmmod hello.ko
```

for more see dmesg log .