# Adding iptables extensions

Tags: root-access, kernel, android-11, iptables

After a huge hustle I managed to compile the xt_DSCP.ko kernel module and it can be loaded with no errors.

```
:/ $ su
:/ # insmod /sdcard/xt_DSCP.ko
:/ #
```

I also managed to pull `iptables` external from androidgooglesource and managed to build `iptables 1.8.4`(same version packaged with the device) with `--enables-static --disable-shared` which bundled all extensions inside the executable.

Now expecting everything to go smoothly I get this error when I try to use the DSCP target

```
:/ $ su
:/ # export T=/data/local/iptables/sbin/iptables
:/ # $T -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DSCP --set-dscp 0
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--set-dscp"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
2|:/ #
```

The whole folder is `chmod -R 777 /data/local/iptables` and `chown -R 0:2000 /data/local/iptables`. I have also tried moving `libxt_DSCP.so` to `/system/lib` and `system/lib64` but with no avail.

I have hit a wall I'm not sure I will be able to climb. External `iptables` was built with `autotools` using `Android NDK r25c`. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
OS specifics:

Model-name: Galaxy M12(rooted with magisk)
Android-version: 11(stock)
Kernel-version: 4.19.111-22482896
```

Comment: `iptables` binary is built statically linked with all the extensions bundled inside. So why are you putting `libxt_DSCP.so` on the device? Seems strange.

Comment: if I insmod the `xt_DSCO.ko` kernel module and run the iptables binary from `/system/bin`, the same error as above appears. Also, copying `libxt_DSCP.so` to `/system/lib` was just a trial and error thing. I really don't know what else to do. The real reason I built iptables from scratch is because I thought the default iptables lacked the extensions but now I'm even more confused.

Comment: If DSCP plugin is statically linked with `iptables` binary, `iptables -m dscp -h`  should show the help for DSCP extension. In other case you should build the binary with `--enable-shared` and provide [`--with-xtlibdir=PATH`](http://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/configure.ac?h=v1.8.9#n31) option to `configure` to specify where `iptables` should look for the extension plugins (shared libraries) in order to dynamically load them.

Comment: ok let me try again. `iptables -m dscp -h` tries to load the `xt_dscp` match. I only have the `xt_DSCP.ko` kernel module for the target and no kernel module for the match. Is this where the error is sourced? Do I need both kernel modules?

Comment: `iptables -m dscp -h` does not try to load the module (`.ko` file). It just prints the help from the statically linked or dynamically loaded plugin (`.so` file). `unknown option "--set-dscp"` error is also due to missing extension plugin, not due to missing extension module. If you are not clear about the terminology, I'd suggest you read the `iptables` extensions documentation.

Comment: In short, you need the module on kernel side, and the plugin on userspace side. Module is loaded using `modprobe` or `insmod`. That's what you have done correctly. Now the `iptables` needs the plugin to interact with the loaded module. You can build the plugin within the `iptables` using `--enable-static`. Or you can build the plugin separately as an `.so` file using `--enable-shared --disable-static` and let the `iptables` load this `.so` file from a directory specified with `--with-xtlibdir=PATH` at compile time.

Comment: well explained indeed. I think the problem is sourced from the `iptables` from androidgooglesource in a sense that it was modified to exclude some of those extensions and maybe that is why the `iptables` from the stock rom excludes them too. I will try to build the same exact version from the netfilter source and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like insmod was at fault here for giving me false hope. According to this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209519/356941) by @Irfan Latif 4 years ago, the `xt_DSCP.ko` module can't be loaded since its not one of the modules listed in `/sys/module` and the only way I can get it to work is to build the kernel from scratch.