# Is it possible to add a driver to my kernel without flashing a new kernel?

Tags: kernel

Is it possible to load a driver as a kernel module into my Galaxy S10, Magisk rooted without having to build a new kernel and flash it?

Comment: None of those have anything to do with being able to load drivers without reflashing a new kernel

Answer (score 1):

Drivers are built as kernel modules i.e. `.ko` files which can be loaded with `modprobe` but for that you have to rebuild kernel with the required module, or it should be compatible with installed kernel if built separately.

The installed kernel should be built with `CONFIG_MODULES=y` in order to load modules. Make sure the version of kernel source code tree or that of header files match with installed kernel version. Otherwise dependencies may break resulting in `Unknown symbol in module` type of errors. Also, if kernel is signed (`CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE`), modules must be signed with the same key to avoid `required keys not available` error.