# How to load android shared libraries

Tags: security, boot, system, kernel, files

How does Android load /system/lib/*.so libraries?
How does the system knows what file is for what purpose. Is there a database or list of expected.so files and their functions?

Comment: Why do you use the word "drivers" in the title and later you correctly name the files libraries? Besides that so libraries are loaded the same way as on on all Linux systems. Search Google for the terms like `Linux` + `linker` `ldd` or `dlopen`.

Comment: "*How to load Android drivers*"? Drivers are [loaded](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214736/218526) as [kernel modules](http://www.bottomupcs.com/organisation_of_os.xhtml#d0e4656) (`.ko` files). // "*How does the system know what file is for what purpose*"? Please read about [dynamic linking](http://www.bottomupcs.com/chapter08.xhtml).

Comment: My bad, I actually don't know why I put drivers in the title, it was a mistake.